# Garbage in string output function

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to write a `printf` replacement in asm and so far have this code:

```
; string is loaded into r8
print_string:
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rsi
    push rdx

    ; load string pointer into ecx
    mov rsi, r8

    ; loop over every char
    print_string_loop0:
        cmp sil, 0 ; stop when encounter null character
        je print_string_return
        mov rax, 1 ; syscall (sys_write)
        mov rdi, 1 ; file descriptor for write (stdout = 1)
        mov rdx, 1 ; bytes to write (1 character)
        syscall
        inc rsi
        jmp print_string_loop0:

    print_string_return:
        pop rdx
        pop rsi
        pop rbx
        pop rax
```

which works, but I always get some sort of garbage after the string that I print.

Heres the code that uses `print_string`

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
    mov r8, string
    call print_string

    mov rax, 60 ; syscall (sys_exit)
    mov rdi, 0  ; exit code
    syscall

.section data

string:
    db "Hell! Oh, World.", 10, 0 ; string, newline, null
```

`print_string` is defined in the same file.

So why is garbage being printed after my string? The garbage is the same every time and if I modify the assembly at all, different garbage is output.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use int 0x80 on 64bit (http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64).  This uses syscall instead of int, and uses different registers.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd thanks for that info! bookmarked. I'll update the question

Comment: Try to replace `cmp cl, 0` by `cmp byte [rcx], 0`.

Comment: @rkhb if you post that as an answer I can accept it. Of course! I wasn't even checking where the pointer pointed, just whether the pointer was non-zero!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got in `R8` and thus in `RSI` an address not a character. So change the break condition `cmp sil, 0` to `cmp byte [rsi], 0`.